# Попадает или подпадает?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Предложение такое:

> "Качество этой продукции подпадает под действие технического регламента."

Скажите пожалуйста, как тут грамотнее сказать: "попадает" или "подпадает"? И есть ли разница между этими понятиями?

Comment: Слушайте, слово "подпадает", на мой взгляд, попадает под юрисдикцию неграмотных людей. У грамотных есть слово "попадает". Объяснение крайне простое

Comment: @Павел если есть объяснение, прошу изложить. И желательно - без этого пренебрежительного обращения сразу ко всем участникам.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь лучше ***подпадает***.

"Подпадает под" - книжный (юридический и административный) синоним для "попадает под" в значении юрисдикции органа, распространения на объект каких-либо положений, норм, законов.
В этом значении слова различаются не значением, но сферой употребления и уровнем официоза.

Comment: К своему стыду, ни разу не слышала вариант "попадает"...

Comment: Ну Вы же, Злата, не каждый день в судах обретаетесь?  
>Павел Лаптев. Правовая система России и европейские правовые стандарты // «Отечественные записки», 2003 В решении о неприемлемости жалобы на нарушение статьи 3 Конвенции по делу «Гусинский против Российской Федерации» от 7 марта 2002 года Суд подчеркнул: «Суд напоминает, что плохое обращение **попадает под действие** статьи 3 Конвенции, если при этом достигнут определенный уровень жестокости."

Comment: Вот еще одно попадение :  
> Борис Руденко. Все возрасту покорны // «Наука и жизнь», 2006 Разрабатывая законы о защите детства или о социальном обслуживании граждан пожилого возраста, необходимо четко знать, **кто именно попадает под их юрисдикцию**.

А вот еще :  
> Лариса Кислинская. Мерседесы в ловушке-2 (2003) Мы проконсультировались с авторитетными специалистами в области права, которые считают, что действия сотрудников таможни носят противоправный характер, что препятствует предпринимательской деятельности и **попадает под соответствующую статью УК РФ**.

Answer (score 0):

Администрация города Екатеринбурга в рамках проекта «Екатеринбург говорит правильно» обращается к вопросу о корректном выборе слова: попадать или подпадать под действие закона?

Специалисты справочно-информационного портала «Русский язык» отмечают, что в этом сочетании принято использовать глагол «подпасть», так как у него есть соответствующее значение — оказаться под воздействием, влиянием кого-либо, чего-либо, в зависимости от кого-либо, чего-либо.

Таким образом, правильно: их работа **подпадает** под действие закона.

[Как правильно: попадать или подпадать под действие закона?](https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/66768-kak-pravilno-popadat-ili-podpadat-pod-deystvie-zakona/)

Comment: Во-первых, нет такоего портала. Во всяеком случае - известного и авторитетного. Во-вторых, какое все это отношение имеет к вопросу?.

Answer (score 0):

люди! 
всё очень просто. есть в украинском языке слово однозначного смысла "підпадає".все кто связан или контактировал с украинским этносом по привычке (неграмотной) суют в русском языке этот подпадает везде где следует быть "попадает". для меня это маркер уже давно. спорить тут не о чем-суржик рулит.